# Magento - How to tell if page hit came from cache or not

Tags: magento

Magento's full page cache is giving us a serious headache, I am looking for a way to tell if a page is being pulled from the FPC or if the page is being generated from scratch.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Jeff

Comment: You mention FPC (an EE feature) but tagged the question as magento-1.7. Which is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe looking at this files helps `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Observer` method `processPreDispatch`

The processor should be `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Processor`

This event `Mage::dispatchEvent('pagecache_processor_metadata_before_save', array('processor' => $this));` on the processor class might help you.